# Trying to set global variable inside a callback nested in forEach loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter, callback

I am working with the Twitter API and I am trying to create a thread. To make a thread, you have to reply to your latest reply to continue the thread, not the original Tweet. To do this, you have to get the tweet id to use for `in_reply_to_status_id` paramater.

The tweet id is accessible in the callback function, where I try to set the global variable `tweetId`. The problem is that the tweet id isn't updating, and all of the replies just go to the same tweet id.

Here is my code.

```
    let tweetId;

    if (tweets.length > 1) {
      // tweet original tweet
      client.post(
        "statuses/update",
        { status: tweets[0] },
        (error, tweet, response) => {
          if (error) return res.status(500).send("Server Error");
          // set tweet id of original tweet to be used for reply
          tweetId = tweet.id_str;

          // loop through all tweets and reply to the latest reply (Creating a thread)
          tweets
            .filter((tweet, i) => i > 0)
            .forEach((tweet) => {
              client.post(
                "statuses/update",
                { status: tweet, in_reply_to_status_id: tweetId },
                (error, tweet, response) => {
                  if (error) return res.status(500).send("Server Error");
                  // set new tweet id to be used for reply
                  tweetId = tweet.id_str;
                }
              );
            });
        }
      );
      res.send("success");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
globalThis.tweetId = tweet.id_str;
```

let will keep it's value only on the same scope.